# MinGW C++ compiler cant find OpenCV in the system path

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

So I'm getting an error stating "fatal error: opencv2\core\mat.hpp: No such file or directory" when trying to compile a small c++ file from .cpp with MinGW. It happens in one form or another in Sublime Text 3, Atom, and on the command line with "gcc myfile.cpp". I should note that I'm on Windows 10. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\core\mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\types.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("despair.jpg");
    cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 1);
    cv::imshow("1", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::Rect_ <char> roi = cv::Rect_ <cv::Point>(cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Point(10, 10));
    cv::rectangle(mask, roi, cv::Scalar(0), -1);
    cv::Scalar colors = cv::mean(img, mask);
}
```

Things I've done and tried:

- Adding C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\ to the system path.
- Adding the bin and lib folders in x64/vc15 folder to the system path.
- Messing and experimenting with the system path in general to try to find anything that might work. (I've tried so many combinations at this point I've forgotten most of them)
- Adding everything to my user specific path.
- Changing the include directory in the .cpp file to be the absolute path to each file I need to include (This works for the exact files I need, but then fails when those files try to include other files *they* need, like when Mat.hpp tries to include Matx.hpp)
- Reinstalling MinGW64.
- Installing MinGW to different folders and updating the system path to reflect the new location.
- Changing which text editor I'm using
- Compiling from the command line outside of a text editor

Things in my system path right now:

- C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib
- C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin
- C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\
- C:\MinGW\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin

I took this code out of a larger project to test what was going on with it and at this point I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what's wrong. Please send help.

Comment: Does adding paths with `-L` and `-I` options help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are those commands I put in the command line? Or options in the set environment variables gui?

Comment: These are mingw command line options. What's your mingw command line to build your project?

Comment: I just used "gcc test_opencv.cpp". How do I use those options? UPDATE: I tried "gcc -L C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include -L C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin -L C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib test_opencv.cpp" does that look right? It gave me the same error as in the OP.

Comment: What is the full path to math.hpp? What is the full path to opencv libraries?

Comment: C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp for that one, and C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib has the opencv_world450.lib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-I` option with path to opencv includes and `-L` with path to opencv libraries, like this:

```
gcc -IC:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include -LC:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib test_opencv.cpp
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this worked. There's a ton of other errors being thrown from opencv for some reason, but I think that's a separate issue probably?

Comment: This issue was about mingw failing to find opencv headers. So yes, opencv compiling errors should be a separate issue.